# $_POST not working. “Notice: Undefined index: SU_UserName

Tags: php

When i try to send data using get method, everything will be ok, but if i tried to send data using post method, Undefined index will appear.

> Error message: Undefined index: SU_UserName

this is the HTML code

```
      <form method="post" action="Login.php">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="SU_UserName" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="SU_NickName">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" name="SU_Email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" name="SU_Password" required>
        </div>

        <div class="loginbox">

          <input type="submit">
        </div>
      </form>
```

and this is Login.php

```
echo $_POST['SU_UserName'];
```

i also used isset(), var_dump($_Post), and the post array size was 0.

Comment: We need to see your `Login.php` code

Comment: I just ran your code and it works.

Comment: @JohnConde - I think your duplicate may be slightly off.  The details of the question suggest that the entire `$_POST` is empty

Comment: you can open google chrome developers and check login.php Headers from network tab.